# cleaner code jQuery multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, code-cleanup

Im using:

```
$("ul.menu").closest(".wrap").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#nav-blackout").css("display", "block");
})
    $("ul.menu").closest(".wrap").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#nav-blackout").css("display", "none");
});
```

however I want the same thing to happen when the mouse enters ul.menu li but if i add that as a multiple selector:

```
 $("ul.menu, ul.menu li").closest(".wrap").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#nav-blackout").css("display", "block");
    })
```

then it would of course still be looking for the closest .wrap which isnt what I want to do - so do I need to have it written out twice (once for closest wrap and once for ul.menu li) or is there a neater way of doing this?

Comment: what's your HTML? can you toss it all into a jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't see the relevancy of the HTML? It's just whether I need to have the same thing written twice for the two different selectors or if it is possible to incorporate the two in the given code?

Comment: no? that is what you're selecting with jquery, right? it's especially relevant attaching event handlers to multiple distinct elements. but, hey, I'm just trying to help; not gonna twist your arm.

Comment: have you ever tried to bring your tires to a garage, telling the technician, that your car makes irregular noises? he would also tell: bring your complete car. this is why we ask for the markup - to test possible solutions and provide the right one!

Comment: It's already been answered with just the code given - the HTML is irrelevant in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `$("ul.menu").closest(".wrap").add('ul.menu li')`;

`$('ul.menu li').closest('.wrap').addBack()` might work as well.

you can also use `.hide()` instead of `.css("display", "none")` and `.show()` for the opposite, while `.toggle()` will alternate the two.

`.hover()` will let you specify mouseenter and mouseleave handlers at the same time.

```
$('ul.menu li').closest('.wrap').addBack().hover(
    function () {  //mouseenter handler
        $("#nav-blackout").show()
    }, function () { //mouseleave handler
        $("#nav-blackout").hide()
    }
);
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks, will accept when I can (have to wait 10 mins)

Comment: `$('.wrap:has(ul.menu), ul.menu li')` might work as well

Comment: or `$('ul.menu li').closest('.wrap').addBack()`

Comment: @DavidFregoli I was just playing with some nastiness like `$('.wrap:has(ul.menu):not(:has(.wrap ul.menu)), ul.menu li')`, but nested `.wrap`s or `.wrap ul`s will not give the same result

Comment: @Rhumborl yes it depends on the html, adding direct child `>` selector helps in those cases